# Capture and assert Log4j output for integration tests using TestNG

Tags: java, log4j, testng, integration-testing

I am writing an integration test using TestNG which needs to check whether a certain log4j DEBUG log is printed after a certain code is executed. I have found some solutions for this in JUnit as in [1](https://slackhacker.com/2009/12/08/testing-logging-behaviour-in-four-code-lines-flat/). But I need a solution in TestNG. I need to assert whether the exact DEBUG log is printed. But I am confused with TestNG's equivalent to the solutions I found. If you have any idea about this, please point out.